# Struggling with designing a cardview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have this design below, but I do not know how to add the title block.

[Design example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llSSF.png)

I currently have this designed in Android Studio: [Design in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muUBN.png)

I am new to Android Studio, so I would be grateful if you could tell me what I am doing wrong if there is any hardcoding :)

My code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@color/homebackground"
tools:context="com.test.test.HomeActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your top level LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and place your Title view outside the CardView

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@color/homebackground"
tools:context="com.test.test.HomeActivity">

<LinearLayout //CHANGE THIS TO RELATIVE LAYOUT
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="25dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

//PLACE YOUR TITLE VIEW HERE 


</LinearLayout>
```

You may have to play with margins a little to get it perfect